# Python: How to print a nested dictionary as a complex table with variable rows?

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, dictionary, string-formatting

Say I have this nested dictionary:

```
d = {'Ben': {'wo_mana': ['Strength = 1.10', 'Speed = 1.50'], 'wi_mana': ['Int = 1.20'], 'Skill': 'true', 'Magic': 'false'},
     'Tom': {'wi_mana': ['Int = 1.40'], 'wo_mana': ['Agility = 1.60'], 'Skill': 'true', 'Magic': 'true'}}
```

The keys and values are not defined by myself, they are actually data extracted from a file.

The number of values for `Skill` and `Magic` is fixed, which is 1.

However, the number of values for `wo_mana` and `wi_mana` is unfixed, which can be 1, 2, 3, 4 etc.

In the example above, `wo_mana` have 2 values for `Ben`.

My goal is to print it in a table (separated with a tab) and when opened in Excel, it looks like this:

```
Name Skill Magic wo_mana          wi_mana
Ben  true  false Strength = 1.10  Int = 1.20
                 Speed = 1.50
Tom  true  true  Agility = 1.60   Int = 1.40
```

Note that for each people, the `wo_mana` and `wi_mana` columns can have multiple rows.

I have tried to use the `csv` module, my code:

```
import csv, itertools

header = ['Name', 'Skill', 'Magic', 'wo_mana', 'wi_mana']

with open('output.csv', 'w') as f:
    w = csv.DictWriter(f, header)
    w.writeheader()
    for key, val in sorted(d.items()):
        row = {'Name': key}
        row.update(val)
        w.writerow(row)
```

My output:

```
Name,Skill,Magic,wo_mana,wi_mana
Ben,true,false,"['Strength = 1.10', 'Speed = 1.50']",['Int = 1.20']
Tom,true,true,['Agility = 1.60'],['Int = 1.40']
```

So it looks like it's not suitable to print the multiple rows part using `csv`

So maybe I have to use `string formatting`? Does anyone know how to print the table like that? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What format do you want the table to be printed in , for the column wo_mana and wi_mana?

Comment: @wolframalpha A table separated with tab or comma, including `Name`, `Skill`, `Magic` as well as `wo_mana` and `wi_mana`, they must in the same table

Comment: @wolframalpha I have stated how I want my table looks like at the beginning of my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go(edited):

```
import csv, itertools
d = {'Ben': {'wo_mana': ['Strength = 1.10'], 'wi_mana': ['Int = 1.20'], 'Skill': 'true', 'Magic': 'false'},
     'Tom': {'wi_mana': ['Int = 1.40'], 'wo_mana': ['Agility = 1.60'], 'Skill': 'true', 'Magic': 'true'}}


header = ['Name', 'Skill', 'Magic', 'wo_mana', 'wi_mana']

with open('output.csv', 'w') as f:
    w = csv.DictWriter(f, header)
    w.writeheader()
    for key, val in sorted(d.items()):
        row = {'Name': key}
        # print val


        wo_mana = [item for item in val['wo_mana']]
        wi_mana = [item for item in val['wi_mana']]
        val['wo_mana'] = wo_mana[0]
        val['wi_mana'] = wi_mana[0]    

        row.update(val)
        w.writerow(row)
        dict_list = []
        if len(wi_mana) > len(wo_mana):

            for index, item in enumerate(wo_mana):
                dict_ = {}
                dict_['wi_mana'] = wi_mana[index]
                dict_['wo_mana'] = wo_mana[index]
                # print dict_

                dict_list.append(dict_)
            [dict_list.append({'wi_mana': item}) for item in wi_mana[len(wo_mana):]]
        else:

            for index, item in enumerate(wi_mana):
                dict_ = {}
                dict_['wi_mana'] = wi_mana[index]
                dict_['wo_mana'] = wo_mana[index]
                # print dict_
                dict_list.append(dict_)
            [dict_list.append({'wo_mana': item}) for item in wo_mana[len(wi_mana):]]
        # print dict_list
        if len(dict_list) > 1:
            [w.writerow(dict_) for dict_ in dict_list[1:]]
```

This works ! Let me know.

Edit: 
According to the question:

> However, the number of values for wo_mana and wi_mana is unfixed, which can be 1, 2, 3, 4 etc.

So I had assumed there would be no KeyError.
According to the modified statements in the comments here is the solution:

It's not tested properly to various conditions and based on what I understood from the comments it works fine, let me know if any problem:

```
import csv, itertools
d = {'Ben': {'Skill': 'true', 'Magic': 'false'},
     'Tom': {'wo_mana': ['Strength = 1.10'], 'wi_mana': ['Int = 1.20', 'O_o'], 'mana': ['Int = 1.20', 'dsadas', 'whatever', '-_-'], 'Skill': 'true', 'Magic': 'true'}}


header = ['Name', 'Skill', 'Magic', 'wo_mana', 'wi_mana', 'mana']

with open('output.csv', 'w') as f:
    w = csv.DictWriter(f, header)
    w.writeheader()
    for key, val in sorted(d.items()):
        row = {'Name': key}
        # print val
        row.update(val)
        dictionary_containing_list = {key: val[key] for key in val if type(val[key])==list}
        if dictionary_containing_list:
            max_length = len(max(dictionary_containing_list.iteritems(), key=lambda x: len(x[1]))[1])
            dict_list = []
            for i in range(max_length):
                dict_ = {}
                for key, val_list in dictionary_containing_list.iteritems():
                    try:
                        dict_[key] = val_list[i]
                    except IndexError:
                        pass
                dict_list.append(dict_)
                row.update(dict_list[0])
            print dict_list
        w.writerow(row)
        if dictionary_containing_list:
            [w.writerow(dict_) for dict_ in dict_list[1:]]
```

The solution is highly generic and you can add as many numbers of `mana`s/ columns and it will work. Remember to append the exact column name to the `header` list!

Comment: Yes, it works! Thank you very much! I will let you know if I encounter any problem.

Comment: Hi, I test your code using my actual file, and I have a `KeyError` while executing this two line `wo_mana = [item for item in val['wo_mana']]` and `wi_mana = [item for item in val['wi_mana']]`, how to execute this line only when `wo_mana` or `wi_mana` exist? because they don't exist for some `Name`

Comment: Alright, I have added these lines `If wo_mana/wi_mana in val.keys():` to check if the keys exist, now I have another problem, what changes should I make if another `key` exist, for example, `mana`, and it is the same as `wo_mana` and `wi_mana`, it can have multiple rows

Comment: So, if I add another `mana`, I will have 9 different cases right? 1) `wo_mana` > `wi_mana` > `mana` 2) `wo_mana` > `wi_mana` < `mana` etc.

Comment: Can you show me how to change the `if len` loop if `mana` is added?

Comment: @TanWenYan  Okay wait for some time ! I will add it.

Comment: sure, no problem. i will be back after lunch

Comment: @TanWenYan check it out!

Comment: I tried not to include the `except IndexError block` first and I really got the `IndexError: list index out of range`. May I know why did this happen? Is adding the `except IndexError block` the only solution to solve this?

Comment: The exception is not the only way to solve the problem of inconsistent length of lists,  if you could also do this by storing the length of the lists explicitly in different variable and get the min length and iterate it over all the list and then 2nd min length and iterate over n-1 lists and so on like I did it in the first case...  To make the program generic I used the above technique so you could add any number of tables with variable lengths without worrying for rewrites!

Comment: Alright, thanks for the explanation. So when an `IndexError` happens, the `pass` will be executed meaning that the `key` and `value` will be added as usual, or it will be ignored and it won't be printed out in the `csv` file?